# Jenkins Access to the params in downstream job

Tags: shell, jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

I sent params to the downstream job like this:

```
build job: '../UItest/master', parameters: [
        string(name: 'parent_branch', value: String.valueOf(BRANCH_NAME)),
        string(name: 'parent_build', value: String.valueOf(BUILD_NUMBER))
      ], wait: false
```

Then in downstream when I try to access it like:

```
sh '''
    echo ${params.parent_branch}
    '''
```

it throws me this error: `${params.parent_branch}: bad substitution`

but I can access to it like:

```
sh "echo ${params.parent_branch}"
```

and it works fine.

so what is differences between `'''` and `"` in running shell script and using params?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer, it is described here: https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html

> Triple-single-quoted '''...''' doesn't support interpolation to use variables like that. We should use Triple-double-quoted """…​""" instead